# Getting the fist row of a query from a list

Tags: sql, partition

I have a table with many tags having time series data
Example:

```
TagName  Value  DateTime              Quality
Tag1      75    09/24/2015 01:05:10    192 
Tag1      76.5  09/24/2015 01:05:20    192 
Tag1      75    09/24/2015 01:05:40    192 
Tag1      74.5  09/24/2015 01:06:00    192 
Tag2      75    09/24/2015 01:05:10    192
Tag2      76.5  09/24/2015 01:05:20    192 
Tag2      75    09/24/2015 01:05:40    192 
Tag2      74.5  09/24/2015 01:06:00    192
```

I need to query the tags (multiple) between StartDate and EndDate and an interval (5min/15 mins)

This Query works:

```
SELECT * FROM   
(SELECT [DateAndTime],[TagName],[Val],row_number()over(partition by datepart(minute, [DateAndTime])order by [DateAndTime] ) as "rn"
FROM [FloatTable]   WHERE
([DateAndTime] BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime) AND 
([TagName] IN (@TagName)) AND
( (DATEPART("n",[DateAndTime]) % @IntervalInMins = 0) )) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

With parameters:

- Interval:5mins
- Tag:'Tag1'
- StartDateTime: '2014-02-26 09:00:00'
- EndDateTime:  '2014-02-26 11:00:00'

Result of query:

```
TagName  Value  DateTime              Quality    
Tag1     75    09/24/2015 01:05:10    192     
Tag1     76.5  09/24/2015 01:10:10    192     
Tag1     75    09/24/2015 01:16:40    192
```

But this works only if we query 1 tag at a time. Typically we want to query a list of tags. If I query a list of tags 'Tag1,Tag2' the query give only results of Tag1. Please advise.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to add `tagname` to the `partition by` and remove the filtering in the `where`:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT [DateAndTime], [TagName], [Val],
             row_number() over (partition by tagname, datepart(minute, [DateAndTime])
                                order by [DateAndTime]
                               ) as rn
      FROM [FloatTable]
      WHERE ([DateAndTime] BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime) AND 
            ( (DATEPART("n",[DateAndTime]) % @IntervalInMins = 0) )
     ) x
WHERE rn = 1
```